# Is the identity a normal function?

Tags: ordinals

I was going to prove the following statement:

> Let $F$ be a normal function, then $\cup\{0,F(0),F(F(0)),\ldots\}$ is the least ordinal $\alpha$ satisfying $F(\alpha)=\alpha$.

In case of $0\neq F(0)$ it is certainly true that none of $F(0),F(F(0)),\ldots$ can be the least fixed point so the above statement would be satisfied. <s>But what if $0=F(0)$? What if $F$ in fact is the identity? Then we had $\cup\{0,F(0),F(F(0)),\ldots\}=\{0\}$ which would not be the least fixed point.</s> /edit: no, see comments and answer below …

So the identity function is a counterexample, or is the identity not a normal function for some reason I am missing?!

Comment: I do not know much about ordinals, but if $F$ is the identity, then I think $\cup \{0, F(0), F(F(0)), ...\}=\cup \{0\}=0$, which is definitely the least fixed point of the identity.

Comment: You're obviously right – no idea what I was thinking there! I will change my question in a minute to avoid opening a new thread.

Comment: Never mind – my stupid mistake was the only obstacle. I posted an answer below for the sake of completeness. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the identity is a normal function, and $\cup\{0\}=\{0\}$ is just rubbish as Noble Mushtak pointed out in the comments.

To prove the cited statement, tick the case $F(0)=0$ as trivial. If $F(0)\neq 0$, suppose $\cup\{0, F(0), F(F(0)),\ldots\}$ was not the least fixed point. Then $F^i(0)$ for some $i\geq 1$ is the least fixed point but then $F^{i-1}(0)<F^i(0)$ whence $F^i(0)<F^{i+1}(0)$ as $F$ is normal. Contradiction!